# Unable to create new session during testing of Android app

Tags: java, android, appium-android

I am trying to develop a test automation on an Android pp, and I have been hitting the "Unable to create new session" My IDE is Eclipse v2020-03 (4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211 with JDK v10.0.2 and Android SDK v25.2.5. The EMulator device is run from Android Studio with the hardware of Nexus One Api 27 ANdroid 8.1 (Google APIs). Appium version is v1.17.1

My Desired Capabilities setup is as follow

```
dc.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");        
dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.mol.wallet.uat");
dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");        
dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");           
dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.mol.wallet.module.start.SplashActivity");        
dc.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", false);
dc.setCapability("noReset", "true");
dc.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
driver_App = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"),dc);
```

When I run my code, it hits error at the last line of the above code, with the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{appPackage=com.mol.molwallet.uat, appActivity=com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity, noReset=true, automationName=UiAutomator2, autoGrantPermissions=false, platformName=Android, deviceName=emulator-5554, resetKeyboard=true}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-GUSLKCQ6', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.lambda$1(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:95)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.doExecute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:111)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:112)
    at FirstFlow.main(FirstFlow.java:94)
```

Let me know also if I have miss out any info for your reference. Thanks

From Appium's log

```
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Welcome to Appium v1.17.1
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Non-default server args:
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   allowInsecure: {
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   }
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   denyInsecure: {
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   }[info] [35m[Appium][39m Welcome to Appium v1.17.1
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Non-default server args:
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   allowInsecure: {
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   }
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   denyInsecure: {
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   }
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}],"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true},"requiredCapabilities":{}}[39m
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true},{},[{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}]]
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1593759682371 (15:01:22 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time))
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Appium v1.17.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.44.2) session
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "appPackage": "com.mol.molwallet.uat",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "appActivity": "com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "noReset": "true",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "autoGrantPermissions": false,
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "platformName": "Android",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "resetKeyboard": true
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m }
[warn] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Capability 'noReset' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[info] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Session created with session id: 59dc0adc-8dfb-4c10-8c60-44df44c8aea1
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Starting 'com.mol.molwallet.uat' directly on the device[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}],"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true},"requiredCapabilities":{}}[39m
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true},{},[{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}]]
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1593759682371 (15:01:22 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time))
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Appium v1.17.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.44.2) session
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "appPackage": "com.mol.molwallet.uat",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "appActivity": "com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "noReset": "true",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "autoGrantPermissions": false,
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "platformName": "Android",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "resetKeyboard": true
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m }
[warn] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Capability 'noReset' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[info] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Session created with session id: 59dc0adc-8dfb-4c10-8c60-44df44c8aea1
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Starting 'com.mol.molwallet.uat' directly on the device
[info] [35m[ADB][39m Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[info] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Retrieving device list
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting connected devices...[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'[debug] [35m[ADB][39m The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('3.1.0' >= '3.1.0')
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f io\\.appium\\.settings'[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell appops set io.appium.settings android\:mock_location allow'
[debug] [35m[Logcat][39m Starting logcat capture[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to 8200
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp\:8200 tcp\:6790'[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Server package at 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' is not writeable. Will copy it into the temporary location at 'C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1v48itp.6vof' as a workaround. Consider making this file writeable manually in order to improve the performance of session startup.
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Server package at 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is not writeable. Will copy it into the temporary location at 'C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1v48itp.6vof' as a workaround. Consider making this file writeable manually in order to improve the performance of session startup.
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'[debug] [35m[ADB][39m C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1v48itp.6vof\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is already zip-aligned. Doing nothing
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Signing 'C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1v48itp.6vof\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' with default cert
[warn] [35m[ADB][39m Cannot use apksigner tool for signing. Defaulting to sign.jar. Original error: JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME.
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[warn] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Did not get confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without session id
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.mol.molwallet.uat'
[debug] [35m[Logcat][39m Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200'[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true},"requiredCapabilities":{}}[39m
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true},{},null]
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1593759685378 (15:01:25 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time))
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Appium v1.17.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.44.2) session
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "appPackage": "com.mol.molwallet.uat",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "appActivity": "com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "noReset": "true",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "autoGrantPermissions": false,
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "platformName": "Android",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m   "resetKeyboard": true
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m }
[warn] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Capability 'noReset' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[info] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Session created with session id: 362fc106-30e6-422e-bc47-8a93160b5977
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Starting 'com.mol.molwallet.uat' directly on the device
[info] [35m[ADB][39m Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[info] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Retrieving device list
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting connected devices...
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Connected devices: [{"udid":"emulator-5554","state":"device"}]
[info] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Using device: emulator-5554
[info] [35m[ADB][39m Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Setting device id to emulator-5554
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 27
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Device API level: 27
[warn] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('3.1.0' >= '3.1.0')
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f io\\.appium\\.settings'
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell appops set io.appium.settings android\:mock_location allow'[debug] [35m[Logcat][39m Starting logcat capture[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to 8200
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp\:8200 tcp\:6790'
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Server package at 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is not writeable. Will copy it into the temporary location at 'C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1t9t20k.09vx' as a workaround. Consider making this file writeable manually in order to improve the performance of session startup.
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Server package at 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' is not writeable. Will copy it into the temporary location at 'C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1t9t20k.09vx' as a workaround. Consider making this file writeable manually in order to improve the performance of session startup.
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'[debug] [35m[ADB][39m C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1t9t20k.09vx\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is already zip-aligned. Doing nothing
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Signing 'C:\Users\lamch\AppData\Local\Temp\202063-17316-1t9t20k.09vx\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' with default cert
[warn] [35m[ADB][39m Cannot use apksigner tool for signing. Defaulting to sign.jar. Original error: JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME.
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[warn] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Did not get confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without session id
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.mol.molwallet.uat'
[debug] [35m[Logcat][39m Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\lamch\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200'[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1593759687332 (15:01:27 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time))
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Encountered internal error running command: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME.
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m     at getJavaHome (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\helpers.js:141:9)
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m     at C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\helpers.js:125:23
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m     at memoized (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:10552:27)
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m     at ADB.signWithDefaultCert (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-signing.js:76:22)
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Destroying socket connection
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[31m500[39m [90m1957 ms - 190[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}]}[39m
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,[{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.mol.molwallet.uat","appActivity":"com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity","noReset":"true","automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":false,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","resetKeyboard":true}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}]]
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1593759687352 (15:01:27 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time))
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1593759687353 (15:01:27 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time))
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m Encountered internal error running command: Error: Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at parseCapsForInnerDriver (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\utils.js:58:14)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AppiumDriver.createSession (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:296:26)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at commandExecutor (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:330:9)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:344:15)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:520:26)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:309:34)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:15
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at next (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Function.process_params (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at next (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at logger (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\morgan\index.js:144:5)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at trim_prefix (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Function.process_params (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at next (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at invokeCallback (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at done (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1168:12)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m Destroying socket connection
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[31m500[39m [90m7 ms - 669[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp and delete all files in Temp folder.Restart Appium .That must fix it.